# How to import package from bundle with Bndtools

Tags: bndtools

I was following this Bndtools tutorial http://bndtools.org/tutorial.html to implement a simple greeting service.

First, I created this interface in bundle `org.example.api`:

```java
package org.example.api;

public interface Greeting {
  String sayHello( String name );
}
```

Then a service that implements the above interface in bundle `org.example.impl`:

```java
package org.example.impl;

import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;

@Component
public class GreetingComponent implements Greeting {
  public String sayHello( String name ) {
    return "Hello " + name;
  }
}
```

Of course, the type `Greeting` cannot be resolved. And here comes my question: what is the designated way to add the package import declaration to the `impl` bundle? I am aware that I could manually edit `bnd.bnd` of `org.example.impl` to include the necessary package in the `-buildpath` directive.

But that is rather inconvenient: memorize the package name, navigate to the appropriate bnd file, edit the directive, save. Isn't here a more convenient way to add the missing import?

I was looking for something like a quick fix (<kbd>Ctrl+1</kbd>) but that doesn't seem to exist.

Answer (score 0):

You have to maintain the Build Path/Bnd Bundle Path and APIs via the bnd.bnd `Bnd Project Editor`. 
Take care to open the correct editor. File association `*.bnd` is in some Eclipse instances associated to Text Editor, instead of Bnd Bundle Editor. 
Open the bnd file with `Bnd Project Editor` and add the bundles for the build path either via

1. Drag-and-Drop from `Repository` view
2. Build Tab - Build Path Section and Button `+` with search functionality
3. `Source Tab` is also an option

IMHO DnD is easiest and fastest way ;-)

Comment: Thank you, Peter, for your reply. Sure, bnd file can be edited (see my question), but I was hoping for something simpler than that. I've opened an enhancement proposal: https://github.com/bndtools/bndtools/issues/1589